# Angular 5 Universal - Server side httpclient get response encode broken

Tags: angular, httpclient, universal, angular-universal, angular5

I'm using Angular 5 Universal and ssr working fine. But When I use httpclient with get request on server side response have encode problem. But Same code working properly on client side

**My code sample:**

```
const getPosts = this.httpClient.get(`${GlobalTexts.rest_url}auth/showcase?limit=20&offset=0`,
      {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'),
      responseType: 'text', observe: 'response'})
      .map(res => res);
         getPosts.subscribe(res => {
           /*const arr = new Uint8Array(res.body);
           const str = String.fromCharCode.apply(String, arr);*/
           this.dogs = res.body;
           console.log(res);
           // console.log(this.dogs);
        });
```

**Server Side Response :**

```
\u001f�\b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000�[K���\u0011�+0}]��\u0013��)+�Q\u0014YVJ^WJ\u0015�\\\u0003`�D\b�[xlµU�C�|��U9�|���\u001ctKy/�K���#�\u0003�OH\u000f�\u0000�ՒK.���}Њ3h\f03�u����\u0013�Bu����\
u0013\u0005�.���l�s2ȋN��>a\u000fU>�H����y��D��ά�ѫt��ڃ�3\u001d�Q?���2ӧQ\u001a�Л��\u0015��?�H\u0003e\r����>4����rv�\u0015���A50�1\u001d�_\u0016q\t7�e���ou�:}\u0015�\u0007�h��i�~u#\u001eN��4��DC��J�ׁW�w\u0007e\n��b�\u00
13Dy�g>Ҵ�L\u0007�/ ..... I cut other parts
```

**Client Side Response :**

```
{"data":[{"id"= 4, "name"="test"}, {"id"= 5, "name" = "test2"}],"success":{"code":200}} -> this is sample, my response is json like that.
```

Thanks...

Comment: I'm getting similar. When I use fiddler to watch the requests, no request goes out and the error message is "unknown error". It just returns immediately. Works perfectly if I go back to Angular 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's about gzip encryption. For now, I disabled gzip. I'll search about other solutions.